# Rails - Install spree commerce on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm following the instructions and I'm writing the commands:
[image: steps]

When I'm writing `brew install imagemagick` I get: 
'brew' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How can I install it properly on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

brew is not a windows command. It is mac command. You are using installation procedure for mac. Follow this for windows installation http://ashutoshpandey.in/installing-spree-commerce-on-a-windows-machine/
For installing the imagemagick you can follow this. [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

Comment: you can install imagemagick http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php

Comment: Which one I choose? there are like 14 downloads

Comment: You will see there is Windows Binary Release. If you machine 64 bit or 32 bit. Depending on it choose anything that will suit you. There is also direction for the installation process.

Comment: I mean, what is it static, or dynamic? there are more than one option of it

Comment: Any of them will the job. No problem.

Comment: Welcome. Its my pleasure.

Comment: after I installed it, when I type spree install I get "Image magick must be installed"

Comment: Did you set the windows imagemagick in environment variables? type `identify -version` check if it is installed ?

Comment: I get: 'identifiy' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Add the executable path in the environment variables. I think this might be the problem.

Comment: what does it mean 'Add the ecexutable path'? I don't understand

Comment: when you install the imagemagick it should installed somewhere in your pc right? Just C:\ImageMagick\bin set it in the environment variables in windows. `go to -> advance system settings -> environment variables -> system variables -> path ->` `C:\ImageMagick\bin` set it adding.

Comment: I have this line already there: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16, why should I create the bin folder?

Comment: in the bin folder all the executes are there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105824/discussion-between-user4571629-and-mohammad-shahadat-hossain).